# $A\hookrightarrow X$ induces an injection $H_n(A)\hookrightarrow H_n(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

> Show that if $(X,A)$ is a CW pair of dimension $n$ (so all cells of $X-A$ have dimension at most $n$) then the map $H_n(A)\to H_n(X)$ induced by the inclusion $A\to X$ is injection with image a direct summand of $H_n(X)$.

Finding a retraction would be impossible but here's one thing: $(X,A)$ is a good pair so $X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$ is a (deformation) retract of $X\times I$. Anyway, any idea how to prove this?

Comment: What is meant by dimension n when talking about the pair?

Comment: @Thorgott It means all cells of $X-A$ have dimension at most $n$.

Comment: Hint: If you consider the cellular homology chain complex, $C_n(X)\cong C_n(A)\oplus \mathbb Z^k$ and the image of $\partial\colon C_{n+1}(X)\to C_n(X)$ lands in $C_n(A)$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Oh I get it. Thanks!